# NSObject PerformSelector Issue

Tags: c++, objective-c, multithreading, memory-management, core-data

Hooooookay so here's another *"I just have no idea what's going on"* problem:

The first time I make a call to `getFullWL()` below, I get all my values as expected.  Each subsequent call, however, returns `nan` instead of the true value(`-nan(0x400000000)` in XCode or something)

Furthermore, if I put my "debug" lines in `SFLog` the value prints as `nan` *but returns the correct value!*  If I comment out `SFLog` (which is just a #define for `NSLog` depending on a level I set - nothing special), then the value is not caught by `isnan()` in `View` but is checked as `isnan()` in `Window`

`Window` and `View` are sitting on one thread, while `DataModule` and `DCMPix` are sitting on another (main thread, I believe).  `DCMPix` also gets some data from a Core-Data object (`fImage` I believe).

```
void Window::PopUp()
{
    // Grab the View from the Pipe Thread and cast it to my local namespace subclass View
    View *view = static_cast< View* >(getPipe()->getView(event.context.view));

    float fullww = view->getFullWW();
    float fullwl = view->getFullWL();
    //SFLog(@"WindowLevel Window %f", wl);

    // set SLider Values
    if (!isnan(fullwl)){
        [[vc winLevel] setMinValue:fullwl];
        [[vc winLevel] setMaxValue:(-1.0f*fullwl)];
    }
}


float View::getFullWL()
{
    float wl = _callPixMethod(@selector(fullwl)).floatValue;
    if ( isnan(wl) ) wl = _wl * 2.0f; //<-- is never detected as NaN here
    //SFLog(@"WindowLevel View %f", wl);  //<-- but is *printed* as NaN here
    return wl;
}

// A Union to "cast" the return from the [object performSelector:] method.
//   Since it returns `id` and (float)(id) doesn't work.
union performReturn {
    id OBJC_ID;
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;
    bool boolValue;
};


performReturn View::_callPixMethod(SEL method)
{
    DataModule* data;
    DataVisitor getdata(&data);
    getConfig()->accept(getdata);
    performReturn retVal;
    retVal.OBJC_ID = data->callPixMethod(_datasetIndex, _datasetID, method);
    return retVal;
}


id DataModule::callPixMethod(int index, std::string predicate, SEL method)
{
    DCMPix *pix =[[getSeriesData(predicate) pixList_] objectAtIndex:index];

    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);

    id retVal = [pix performSelector:method];

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);

    return retVal;
}

// DCMPix.m (from API, can't change)
- (float) fullwl
{
 if( fullww == 0 && fullwl == 0) [self computePixMinPixMax];
 return fullwl;
}

- (void)computePixMinPixMax
{
    float pixmin, pixmax;

    if( fImage == nil || width * height <= 0) return;

    [checking lock];

    @try 
    {
        if( isRGB)
        {
            pixmax = 255;
            pixmin = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            float fmin, fmax;

            vDSP_minv ( fImage,  1, &fmin, width * height);
            vDSP_maxv ( fImage , 1, &fmax, width * height);

            pixmax = fmax;
            pixmin = fmin;

            if( pixmin == pixmax)
            {
                pixmax = pixmin + 20;
            }
        }

        fullwl = pixmin + (pixmax - pixmin)/2;
        fullww = (pixmax - pixmin);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) 
    {
        NSLog( @"***** exception in %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, e);
    }

    [checking unlock];
}
```

Help!  Why would I not be getting the correct value in `Window`?

I also get no `nan`'s when calling `view->getFullWW()` even though it follows the same execution path. (but calls `@selector(fullww)`)

No Errors or exceptions are thrown.  Just that bizarre behavior.

Thanks!

---

After further testing, the following change makes all the difference:

```
float View::getFullWL()
{
    float wl = _callPixMethod(@selector(fullwl)).floatValue;
    if ( isnan(wl) ) wl = _wl * 2.0f; //<-- is never detected as NaN here
    NSLog(@"WindowLevel View %f", wl);  //<-- is *printed* as NaN here
    return wl; //<-- returns expected value
}

float View::getFullWL()
{
    float wl = _callPixMethod(@selector(fullwl)).floatValue;
    if ( isnan(wl) ) wl = _wl * 2.0f; //<-- is never detected as NaN here
    return wl; //<-- returns `nan`
}
```

---

After more testing, it doesn't matter where I put the NSLog() statement, if it occurs before `float fullwl =` is assigned.

```
void Window::PopUp()
{
    // Grab the View from the Pipe Thread and cast it to my local namespace subclass View
    View *view = static_cast< View* >(getPipe()->getView(event.context.view));

    float fullww = view->getFullWW();
    NSLog("Putting this here, makes fullwl work.  Removing it, stores fullwl as nan");
    float fullwl = view->getFullWL();
    //SFLog(@"WindowLevel Window %f", wl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whelp, Here I am answering my own question *again* but the answer is... [RTFM](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:).

> The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Tasks/invocations.html).

So the answer is, use `NSInvocation` and not `[obj performSelector:]`